# Viewpager2 not scrolling inside Horizontal ReyclerView

Tags: kotlin, android-viewpager2, horizontal-recyclerview

I am stuck with very common issue but not getting proper solution , the requirement is to create Horizontal Recyclerview and add a Viewpager2 as an item to Horizontal Recyclerview. The problem is Horizontal Recycelrview is working properly but Viewpager scroll is not working inside it I tried 1. Nestedscrolling to be set true/ false
2. Recyclerview inside of Scrollview
3. Viewpager insde of Scrollview
but all these doesn't work here.
I know the approach is not good but can not change the requirement. Also this kind of questions have already asked and I tried so many examples but they are not fixing my problem.
Please find the snap below for better understanding.
I can share the code if needed.
[image: Snap]

Thanks in advance and any help would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

**I made this simple solution for the same issue**

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
    int action = e.getAction();
    switch(action) {
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        startX = e.getX();
        startY = e.getY();
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        int first = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        int fistCom = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        int last = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
        int lastCom = layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        if (e.getX() < startX) {
          if (lastCom == listFrontTemplateData.size()-1) {
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
          }
        } else if (e.getX() > startX) {
          if (fistCom == 0) {
            rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
          }
        }
        break;
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        rv.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        break;
      }
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(@NonNull RecyclerView rv, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {}
});
```

`listFrontTemplateData` is my `arraylist`

first of all, add an item touch listener in `Recyclerview` to get which item you have touched and get its X and Y position.

Now inside the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method, I get the touch event for the InterceptTouch parent view pager touch. And write some code for if `Recyclerview` last item or fist item visible so `viewpager2` `InterceptTouch` enable and move to next or previous page in viewpager2.